# How to get notified when an autoscaled(aws) node chef-client run fails/succeed ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, autoscaling

Am configuring the chef( via user data script) for autoscaling group in AWS. I would like to get notified if the chef-client first run fails or succeed during the process of auto scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Chef handler system: https://docs.chef.io/handlers.html

There are existing handlers for email, IRC, Slack, HipChat, Splunk, Logstash, and plenty more, or you can write your own that does whatever specific notification behavior you want.